# Axapta: Programmatically switch records in a form

Tags: forms, treeview, axapta

In Dynamics AX 2009, how do you programmatically change to a different record in a form?

My form contains a treeview and a group of bound data fields.  When clicking on a record in the tree (the data value for each item in the tree is the RecId of the item I'd like to edit in the form) I'd like to change the form to that record.

I've been using sysSetupForm as an example for working with a tree, but I'm having trouble isolating where the call to change records occurs in their code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some example:

```
some_table   table;
;
table = some_table:find(recid);
table_ds.findRecord(table);   // it's a form datasource method
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Worked perfectly.